# Retrofit android header User-Agent not showing on Log

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, user-agent

i do an interceptor and set header User-Agent like this

```
public class UserAgentInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private final String userAgent;

public UserAgentInterceptor(String userAgent) {
    this.userAgent = userAgent;
}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request originalRequest = chain.request();
    Request requestWithUserAgent = originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .header("User-Agent", userAgent)
            .build();
    return chain.proceed(requestWithUserAgent);
}
```

}

and i add log showen like this

```
  private RestAdapter getRestAdapterFromUrl(String url)
{
    OkHttpClient okHttp = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttp.setConnectTimeout(18000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    okHttp.setReadTimeout(18000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // On ajoute user agent intercepteur

    okHttp.networkInterceptors().add(new UserAgentInterceptor(VersionUtil.getUserAgent()));


    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(url)
            .setClient(new RestoflashClientWrapper(new OkClient(okHttp)))
            //.setConverter(new retrofit.converter.JacksonConverter(jsonMapperUnwrapped))
            .setConverter(new JacksonConverter(jsonMapper,jsonMapperUnwrapped))
                    //.setRequestInterceptor(new RestoFlashRequest())
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);

    builder.setRequestInterceptor(interceptor);
    builder.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.HEADERS_AND_ARGS).setLog(new AndroidLog("RETROFIT_LOG"));
    return builder.build();
}
```

and also instead of RestAdapter.LogLevel.HEADERS_AND_ARGS . i tried RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL but on the log i can' see the User-Agent header on the log of android studio ?

thanks you for helping

Comment: What is RestoflashClientWrapper and OkClient ? they may lose interceptors from okhhtp.
I sugget to place breakpoint on your interceptor to be sure that it's called .

Comment: I already do that i m sure that i go throught interceptor

Answer (score 0):

personally I had the same problem.

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder()
.addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
```

And i had to add an interceptor that explicitly log the headers.

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();
    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder();
    /*log debug info*/
    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    for (int i = 0; i < request.headers().size(); i++) {
        Timber.tag("OkHttp").d(String.format("%s: %s", request.headers().name(i), request.headers().value(i)));
    }
    return chain.proceed(request);
}
```

And I also use a CurlInterceptor that allows to log a "curl", which is useful if you want to test quickly via tools such as "Postman".

CurlInterceptor sample [here](https://github.com/MaximeJallu/Drop/blob/master/CurlLogInterceptor.kt)

Hoping to have answered your need!